# C++ incomplete type is not allowed class inner use?

Tags: c++, class, types, nested

I have a header `Room.h` defined as follows:

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

class Room
{
public:
    Room();

private:
    Room north;
    Room south;
    Room east; 
    Room west;
};

#endif
```

But I get `Error: incomplete type is not allowed` for each of the `Room` variables. Is there a fundamental flaw in this kind of design?

Comment: Think about what, *exactly*, you're asking this to do. What is in the room `north`, for example. Hmmmmm......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short Answer

Use pointer.

```
private:
Room* north;
...
```

### Long Answer

C++ compiler need know size of Class. `Error: incomplete type is not allowed`, because cannot compute size.

Use pointer. Because compiler can compute size of `pointer`.

PS : I'm not good at english

Comment: Thanks, was a rookie mistake by me!

Comment: Best short answer ever.  Effective use of English

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the design is fatally flawed. You're saying each room contains four other rooms. Each of those would then contain four more rooms--and each of those four more rooms, and so on indefinitely. In short, what started as a single room contains infinite other rooms.

You can create a room that contains pointers to four other rooms. Then you can create rooms for those to connect to, but (importantly) when you get to the end of a chain, you can create a room that has null pointers in directions where there are no more rooms.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Room` type before completely defining it (from definition the compiler deduce the `size` which is required to create an object), and since it is *same type* inclusion, will lead to infinite definition. You can add pointer or reference to `Room` instead of object.

```
class Room
{
  public:
    Room();

  private:
   Room* north;
   Room* south;
   Room* east; 
   Room* west;
};
```